# How to prove if a heuristic function is admissible or not

Tags: heuristics

[image: Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem]

Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Euristic is ammisible if and only if not overestimate the result. 
My hint is check if your euristic follow this rule. Check the cost of your euristic, with simple substitution.
Good euristic for your problem is movements cost 1.

I hope that help you.